# How to catch event when click pause/play button on MediaController

Tags: android, event-handling, mediacontroller

How to catch event when click pause/play button on MediaController.

i try onKey,onTouch - and then i click on pause/play button on MediaController did nothing happened.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934556/event-for-videoview-playback-state-or-mediacontroller-play-pause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a late answer, but I posted a solution to an identical question [overhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934556/event-for-videoview-playback-state-or-mediacontroller-play-pause/8046523#8046523), in case you're still looking (or others that perhaps bump into this...)

//Edit: ups, didn't notice someone already posted a link as comment...